# CSS3 menu shape, style

Tags: css

Can anyone tel me how I would make a shape like this in CSS, with the triangle centered top or bottom like I want it ?

[image]

**Edit:**

With one element.

Comment: So it would be a star's top or bottom half plus a rectangle in my mind..

Comment: Does it have to be with one div?

Comment: that would be ideal yes, As I would like to use it on menu li items

Comment: Because it would be rather easy to do with 2 divs, one with the triangle and one with the rectangle.

Comment: I found this http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/

Comment: Ah yeah, it looks like there is only one element, but uses the :after to create an "invisible" second element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@harry; there are lot of ways to create this type of triangles arrows. I edit @jam fiddle & center the arrows.

CSS:

```
div
{
    background: #76a7dc;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline;
    position:relative;
}

div:after
{
    border-color: #76a7dc transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 0;
    content: "";
    margin-top: 5px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    margin-left:-10px;
    left:50%;
    bottom:-9px;
}
```

check this example http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/wWykY/2/

Comment: how would you do that on a list of li's, each a menu item

Answer (score 1):

There's [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/wWykY/), which will do mostly what you want. However, the "pointy bit" will only align to the left. I suggest you take a look at [these examples](http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/) and see if there are any that are similar to what you want.

---

To center the arrow underneath the box, give it a `left: 15px` property, providing the box's width is `50px`. This will center the arrow, but the only issue is that you will have to manually set the position. Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/wWykY/3/).

Comment: With those examples, how would you center align the pointer? Js?

Comment: You just need to use the property indicated with  `/* controls XXXXXX position */` in the css http://nicolasgallagher.com/pure-css-speech-bubbles/demo/default.css

Comment: @Harry I've edited the JSFiddle with an example. Please see my edits.