# How to create a pricetag shape in CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

So I've found this answer  - [CSS3 menu shape, style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330027/css3-menu-shape-style) but have no idea on how to put it on the left side. I've searched for it already but with no luck.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And I've found this one also - [Change the shape of the triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592617/change-the-shape-of-the-triangle). How can I make it work on the opposite side? I mean the arrow needs to be on the left side. And is it possible to do this with one `div`?

Comment: A long time ago, I did a jquery plugin to display callouts without images: https://github.com/lepe/jquery-yacop . The trick is on the CSS. Give it a look and you may find what you need. (demo is here: http://yacop.alepe.com/callout.htm)

Comment: You can do with pseudo elements like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/L65oetvL/1/). If you want the triangle's border to have a darker color in screenshot then you should use transforms (rotate) unlike that linked answer which uses border hack.

Comment: [**This**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/L65oetvL/3/) sample is more similar to what you need.

Comment: @Harry in latest Firefox its appear weierd

Comment: aah I see your DEMO is most perfect..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Want one that you can put  over any background color?**

[image: simple Price tag shape in css, html]

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/deroguse/1/edit)**

Only this HTML:

```
<span class="pricetag"></span>
```

And this CSS:

```
.pricetag{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 0 25px 0 15px;
    background:#E8EDF0;
    border: 0 solid #C7D2D4;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    color:#999;
    line-height:23px;
}
.pricetag:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin:1px 7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
    content:"\00D7";
}
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0px;
    text-indent:12px;
    left:-15px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-right:14px solid #E8EDF0;
    border-top:  13px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  13px solid transparent;
}
```

which basically follows this principles: [How to create a ribbon shape in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24207341/how-to-create-a-ribbon-shape-in-css)

---

### If you want to add borders all around:

[image]

**[jsBin demo with transform: `rotate(45deg)` applied to the `:before` pseudo](http://jsbin.com/jajicena/1/edit)**

```
.pricetag{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 0 25px 0 15px;
    background:#E8EDF0;
    border: 1px solid #C7D2D4;
    color:#999;
    line-height:23px;
}
.pricetag:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin:1px 7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
    content:"\00D7";
}
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    background:#E8EDF0;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #aaa;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:13px;
    text-indent:6px;
    top:3px;
    left:-10px;
    width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-left:1px solid #C7D2D4;
    border-bottom:1px solid #C7D2D4;
}
```

Comment: Oh I think this one is more appropriate but how can I make the width dynamic? So that it will contain the text inside

Comment: @user3093453 instead of `width` use: `padding: 0 25px 0 15px;` I'll edit my answer

Comment: The usage of the degree sign is really clever, but I almost wonder whether U+25CB WHITE CIRCLE `○` would be better.

Comment: @icktoofay In any case you don't have a font that has a white background and a gray border :( Your pick is just bigger than mine 'degree' `°` and it's harder to set a proper line-height.

Comment: @Roko: You might be able to fake it with U+25CF BLACK CIRCLE `●` with `color: white; text-shadow: 0 0 1px gray;`.

Comment: @icktoofay nice idea. let me try

Comment: @Roko: I ended up with [something that looked decent](http://jsbin.com/witasuku/2/edit). Still very mildly annoying that the tag doesn’t have a border on it, but I’m not sure much can be done without adding another element.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan lastly how can I make the text to vertically align in the middle? Because when I add padding it does not seem to be good.

Comment: @icktoofay look at my edited answer. Should be brilliant. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan How bout adding some border on the arrow? Is it possible?

Comment: @Roko: Perhaps the last suggestion: you might want to turn some of the Unicode characters into escapes (e.g. `●` → `\25CF`) so if the browser guesses the text encoding wrong (say, UTF-8 misinterpreted as Latin-1) you won’t end up with some nonsense character like `â`.

Comment: @icktoofay please can you add all those info to my answer? It would be nice from you.

Comment: @user3093453 here's with the rounded arrow and some shadows: http://jsbin.com/lefuk/4/edit Happy coding

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Do you know how to do this Sir? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394709/how-to-make-horizontal-line-with-arrow-using-css?noredirect=1#comment39607606_25394709

Comment: This the most detailed and easily adaptable pure-CSS price-tag design solution I've found. Excellent.

Answer (score 4):

Since the example image in the question has extra outer borders, achieving it with the border trick will involve multiple (pseudo) elements and will become complex (because in addition to the arrow shape, a circle is also needed in front). Instead, the same could be achieved by using `transform: rotate()` like in the below sample.

The approach is pretty simple and as follows:

- The parent `div` container houses the text that should be present within the price-tag shape.
- The `:after` pseudo-element has `transform: rotate(45deg)` and produces the triangle shape. This is then positioned absolutely with respect to the left edge of the parent. The `background` set on the pseudo-element prevents the left border of the parent container from being visible.
- The `:before` pseudo-element forms the circle  present on the left side (using `border-radius`).
- The X mark at the end is added using a `span` tag and the `&times;` entity.
- The parent `div` container's `width` is set to `auto` so that it can expand based on the length of the text.

**Note:** This sample uses transforms, so will require polyfills in lower versions of IE.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  background: #E8EDF2;
  color: #888DA3;
  line-height: 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid #C7D2DB;
}
div:after,
div:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border: 1px solid #C7D2DB;
}
div:after {  /* the arrow on left side positioned using left property */
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  background: #E8EDF2;
  border-color: transparent transparent #C7D2DB #C7D2DB;
  left: -6px;
  top: 2px;
}
div:before {  /* the circle on the left */
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  left: 0px;
  top: 7px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.right {  /* the x mark at the right */
  text-align: right;
  margin: 0px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div>Home<span class='right'>&times;</span>
</div>
<div>Home Sweet Home<span class='right'>&times;</span>
</div>
<div>Hi<span class='right'>&times;</span>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/L65oetvL/)

Comment: How can I add padding on it? So that it will have some breathing room for the text?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted a simplified version of what was proposed here (without the hole effect and borders) but with the pointing side of it with rounded corner as well. So I came up [with this solution](http://codepen.io/leandroico/pen/eWmxLE). Visually this is what you get:

[image: Tag shaped elements]

The HTML for it:

```
<div class="price-tag">Marketing</div>
<div class="price-tag">Sales</div>
<div class="price-tag">Inbound</div>
```

And the CSS for it:

```
.price-tag {
  background: #058;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  padding: 0 0.666rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
.price-tag:after {
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  height: 22px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: 4px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 22px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.price-tag:hover {
  background: #07b;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up for others: if you place this inside an element (e.g. div) which has a background-color, you might be scratching your head as to why the triangle part is not showing. It is, but it's _behind_ the background, so it's obscured (because of the z-index: -1). Had me scratching my head for a while.

Answer (score 0):

[original example](http://jsfiddle.net/waJaY/)

Modified: http://jsbin.com/ruxusobe/1/

Basically, it needs to float left, use border-right (instead of left) and modify the padding.

CSS:

```
.guideList{
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 125px;
}

.guideList li{
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 0px;
}

.guideList .active{
    background-color: #0390d1;
    color: white;
}

.guideList .activePointer{
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-top: 11px solid white;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 11px solid white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="guideList">
    <li><a>Consulting</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span class="activePointer"></span>Law</li>
    <li><a>Finance</a></li>
    <li><a>Technology</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example...

**[Orignal Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7330254/3739658)**

**[Edited Version](http://jsbin.com/funacayu/1/edit)**

**CSS:**

```
div {
    margin-left: 15px;
    background: #76a7dc;
    border: 1px solid #CAD5E0;
    padding: 4px;
    width:50px;
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    content:'';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: -1.3em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-color: transparent #76a7dc transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
}
```

Notice on `border-color`, only `right` is set with a color and everything else is set to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

using `pseudo` element and a little bit playing with `border` you can achieve the exact thing. Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dawupaye/1)**.

**HTML code is :**

```
<a class="arrow" href="#">Continue Reading</a>
```

**CSS Code is:**

```
body{padding:15px;}  
.arrow {
    background: #8ec63f;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding: 0 12px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #8ec63f;

    }
    .arrow:before {
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    }
    .arrow:before {
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid #8ec63f;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    left: -15px; 
    }

   .arrow:hover {
    background: #f7941d;
    color: #fff;
     border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #f7941d;
    }
    .arrow:hover:before {
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;;
    border-right: 15px solid #f7941d;
    }
```

Comment: @user3093453 This DEMO have fluid width. Only one drawback is there is circle not added at first.