# How to make a navigation with horizontal line with arrow using CSS

Tags: css

How can I create a horizontal line with arrow(indicator as active link) like so. [image]

Comment: we are not here to write code for you, please show us what you've tried. to point you in the right direction, i would use a `border-bottom` and then an `:after` psuedo element on the nav items that looks like the arrow. have a look at something like http://cssarrowplease.com for more info on arrow generation

Comment: @haxxxton Pardon for that Sir. I tried searching it but gives me no luck I'm new to this so I'm not aware of it. And also I can't make it work.