# How do I adjust triangle in css price tag to the right size

Tags: html, css

I am following this thread

[How to create a pricetag shape in CSS and HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25195526/how-to-create-a-pricetag-shape-in-css-and-html)

It seems kind of helpful but i am having a hard time adjusting the shapes of the price tag to the right size. The goal is I want to enlarge the price tag so that two lines of text can fit in. And my issue is the triangle, which i tried tweaking it and it doesn't make it fit the rectangle when I adjust to the right size.

Here is the original form
http://jsfiddle.net/LLdcmutx/

html

```
<span class="pricetag">Blueberry Cake $350</span>
```

css

```
.pricetag{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 20px 30px 40px 15px;
    background:#E8EDF0;
    border: 0 solid #C7D2D4;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    color:#999;
    line-height:23px;
}
.pricetag:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin:1px 7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
    content:"\00D7";
}
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0px;
    text-indent:12px;
    left:-15px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-right:14px solid #E8EDF0;
    border-top:  13px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  13px solid transparent;
}
```

Here is what i've tried
http://jsfiddle.net/usobouw4/1/

changes edited: padding, border-right, border-top, border-bottom

html

```
<span class="pricetag">Blueberry Cake <br> $350</span>
```

css

```
.pricetag{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    displaY:inline-block;
    height:25px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 20px 30px 40px 15px;
    background:#E8EDF0;
    border: 0 solid #C7D2D4;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    color:#999;
    line-height:23px;
}
.pricetag:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin:1px 7px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
    content:"\00D7";
}
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0px;
    text-indent:12px;
    left:-15px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-right:41px solid #E8EDF0;
    border-top:  40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  40px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check it out, [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/usobouw4/2/)

```
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0px;
    text-indent:12px;
    left:-42px; // <-- increase this
    top: 0; // <-- add this
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-right:41px solid #E8EDF0;
    border-top:  43px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  43px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give the border bottom and top in the `:before` selector the half of the element hight. So, it should be something like this:

```css
.pricetag{
    white-space:nowrap;
    position:relative;
    margin:0 5px 0 10px;
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
    padding: 0 25px 0 15px;
    background:#E8EDF0; 
    border: 0 solid #C7D2D4;
    border-top-width:1px;
    border-bottom-width:1px;
    color:#999;
    line-height:23px;
}
.pricetag:after{
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    margin:1px 7px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:19px;
    content:"\00D7";
}
.pricetag:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:"\25CF";
    color:white;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #333;
    font-size:11px;
    line-height:0px;
    text-indent:12px;
    left:-15px;
    width: 1px;
    height:0px;
    border-right:14px solid #E8EDF0;
    border-top:  25px solid transparent;
    border-bottom:  25px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<span class="pricetag">Blueberry Cake <br>$350</span>
```